# How to Remove Red JFormDesigner Evaluation Text?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jform-designer

I installed JFormDesigner for IntelliJ with an evaluation license to convert some forms from NetBeans, and upon realizing that it put a huge ugly watermark on every single UI panel, I promptly removed it and deleted all of the .jfd files.  However, the watermarks are still there, even after cleaning and rebuilding the project three times, and I can't figure out what's making them stick around.

Image:
[image: Image of my UI preview in NetBeans, showing a red "JFormDesigner Evaluation" label at the bottom.]

Does anyone know how to remove these labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use JFormDesigner and find generate Java code has the text, I just delete it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is to add a random JLabel in NetBeans to every single JPanel and remove it again.  That'll force the NetBeans Form Designer to regenerate the code.