# JFormDesigner watermark Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, watermark, jform-designer

I got a free trial License for [JFormDesigner](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/274-jformdesigner) on Intellij. I made a couple of forms and everything was great,no watermark or anything. Now I am making a panel consisting of 2 custom panels,ones I made with JFormDesigner. I combined the panels in a 3rd container,and I got myself 3 watermarks when there wasn't a single one in any of my forms. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589935/how-to-remove-red-jformdesigner-evaluation-text) for Netbeans,tried it and nothing updated. I am not sure what on earth I did and the watermarks reappeared. In the generated code,as the Netbeans question says,there is nothing about a red Watermark Label. I can't find the source to delete it. Anyone faced this issue with JFormDesigner on Intellij?
Running on Intellij 2021.2.3 Community Edition and Ubuntu 21.10

[image](https://imgbb.com/2cr8J5M)

Edit: Copy pasting the code in a new COMPLETELY random class,without the comments or anything,generates the same watermark.Im going insane

Answer (score 0):

Found it. There is this line of code :

```
setBorder(new javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder(new javax.swing.border.TitledBorder(new
                javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0), "JF\u006frmDesi\u0067ner Ev\u0061luatio\u006e", javax
                .swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.BOTTOM, new java
                .awt.Font("Dialo\u0067", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12), java.awt
                .Color.red), getBorder()));
```

Notice the line `"JF\u006frmDesi\u0067ner Ev\u0061luatio\u006e"`
The little rats added unicode so Ctrl F wouldnt catch it.Just remove those 2 lines of code and the watermark is gone.